# Python-Sqlite3: Placeholder for a single variable within a for loop of a list gives: sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Need to check why the below code returns an error for a single placeholder whose value is populated via a list; however looping through a dict with two placeholders works fine. I have gone through seemingly similar questions but this seems to be a different scenario. Error reads:
**cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Vip_type VALUES (?,)''', (item,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error**

```
    import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('vip.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
v_lst = ['v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4']
for item in v_lst:
    cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Vip_type VALUES (?,)''', (item,))
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the `,` to be the problem. Try

`cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Vip_type VALUES (?)''', (item,))`

instead.

Comment: I tried that as well before posting but not working, Error here: cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Vip_type VALUES (?,)''', (item))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Comment: If I test your code without the <code>,</code> on a table with one column, it works.

Comment: I have a table with two columns. the first should AUTOINCREMENT as a primary key and the other should obtain its values from the aforementioned table. Can you pls check with this table schema below : CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vip_type(
vip_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
vip TEXT)

Comment: In such case insert NULL for the field that autoincrements. Like `cur.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Vip_type VALUES (NULL,?)''', (item,))`.

Comment: It works but with an observation that the "OR IGNORE INTO" part of the query does not work and if I run the script again, it populates the database with the same set of v_lst parameters and increments the id. Do you have any hint on why the  "OR IGNORE INTO"  isn't working in this case? thanks

Comment: I think because `vip` is not set to be UNIQUE. Your table will accept duplicate values for that column.